# VBA Determine Series Count And Delete

Tags: excel, vba, charts, series

I have some code that creates a dynamic chart using named ranges. The chart should only have 5 series, but for some reason it creates with more than this. I would therefore like to determine how many series the chart has, and delete all series above SeriesCollection(5). I am sure the way I have done this is quite inefficient, and it has broken down several times (due to the Invalid Parameter error). How can I code this task in an efficient way, without the need to handle errors? The code I have currently used is:

```
With ActiveChart
    If .SeriesCollection.Count = 6 Then
       .SeriesCollection(6).Delete
    End If
    If .SeriesCollection.Count = 7 Then
       .SeriesCollection(6).Delete
       .SeriesCollection(7).Delete
    End If
    If .SeriesCollection.Count = 8 Then
       .SeriesCollection(6).Delete
       .SeriesCollection(7).Delete
       .SeriesCollection(8).Delete
    End If
End With
```

Comment: The best solution is really to figure out why you are getting too many series and not add them in the first place.

Comment: I agree, although that's easier said than done!

Answer (score 2):

Looking after these lines:

```
If .SeriesCollection.Count = 7 Then
```

You delete `SeriesCollection(6)` which executes fine.  But, the way collections work is sequentially, so what was `SeriesCollection(7)` gets shifted down into the `(6)` spot.  Then, when you go to delete `(7)` it's not there anymore and you get an error.  Try this:

```
If .SeriesCollection.Count = 7 Then

   .SeriesCollection(7).Delete

   .SeriesCollection(6).Delete

End If

If .SeriesCollection.Count = 8 Then

   .SeriesCollection(8).Delete

   .SeriesCollection(7).Delete

   .SeriesCollection(6).Delete

End If
```

Let us know if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, that ultimately will boil down to less lines of code for you AND not have to worry about having to add a bunch of if statements to account for the "worst case scenario".  Also, if you have less than 6 series, it will skip over the deleting all together:

```
Sub test()
Dim seriesCount As Long
Dim counter As Long

With ActiveChart
    seriesCount = .SeriesCollection.Count

    For counter = seriesCount To 6 Step -1
        .SeriesCollection(counter).Delete
    Next counter
End With
End Sub
```

And as CodeJockey pointed out..when deleting, always go from the bottom up (keep this bit of information handy for when you want to loop through rows and delete those).

Answer (score 0):

I think the key point of understanding here is that the list of series for your chart is renumbered to be continuous 1...N every time you delete a series. So if you have 8 series, you have series indices 1...8. If you then delete seriesCollection(6), now you have series numbered 1...7. But note you still have a seriesCollection(6) -- it's the series that was at indice 7 before the delete step.

Here is my code suggestion:

```
Do While .SeriesCollection.Count > 5
    .SeriesCollection(6).Delete
Loop
```